# Whats the difference between Field and Variable?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, variables, field

I've been using Visual studio to develop a C++ application. I'm not an expert in C++, neither other languages derived from C like C#. So, studying [visual studio's symbology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I found a reference for the same symbol saying "Field or Variable". Correct if I'm wrong please, but this sounds to me pretty almost like "Method or Function" definition.

In C++ there are no methods, instead they are commonly called as functions. So, in C++ there are also no Fields, it's a particularity from C# which works like a variable except that it should be private and it needs to be accessed from a "Get" call. Am I wrong?

Comment: There are methods in C++, in objects and classes.

Comment: Also, a "field" probably refers to a member.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus He was referring to the fact that C++ calls them member functions, not methods.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus so, u mean I can create an independent function based on C and not associate it to my class which would turn it into a method?

Comment: Yeah, I think you did based on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all variables are fields.  Local variables of a method are variables, but not fields.  Parameters to a method, property, constructor, or anonymous method are variables, but are not fields.

Not all fields are variables.  A `const` member is technically a field, but it is not a variable.

Comment: Even the const variables are called variables, despite of the fact that well, they cannot vary.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster You have a source for that?  [The MSDN page for const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) specifically says, "Constant fields and locals aren't variables".

Comment: @Servy to complete your answer, fields do exist then in C++ or it's just a concept from C#?

Comment: @VictorOliveira To the best of my knowledge the term "field" has an identical meaning on both languages.

Comment: @Servy Well, it's more clear to me now; Although I will wait a bit more so se others opinion, if you don't mind, before I accept your answer.

Comment: @Servy well, I have not documentation at all, but if you [google const variables](https://www.google.es/search?q=const%20variables) you can find lots of conversations about it; it is a jargoon or it is accepted as a concept?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I see lots of results, but nothing from any official sources (in any context).  I only see the term used by programmers using the terms on forums and q/a sites, despite the fact that it's not technically a valid term.

Comment: @Servy so is a jargoon definitely?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster In C#, yes, in C++, I'm quite confident.  In other languages, that will depend.  And I wouldn't call it a jargon, simply an improper use of a term.